# PHPExcel stops in the middle of the execution

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read excel and store it in database. 
It is working fine when the number of record is (less say less than 500).
If have records upto 2000 in excel, it stops in the middle (after 400 - 500 rows loaded) without any error .

**Note:** I am using sqlite to reduce memory usage but still i am facing issue...

Here is my code. Please suggest to make it workable.

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    set_time_limit(0) ;
    //Set memory limit to maximum...

       ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');



/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    include $unsecured_param['home_dir'].'APIs/PHPExcelReader/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    //echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
    //if you only want to read certain cells within worksheets, you can add a filter:
                $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';

    /**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */
        class chunkReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
        {
        private $_startRow = 0;
        private $_endRow = 0;
        /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */
        public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) {
        $this->_startRow    = $startRow;
        $this->_endRow      = $startRow + $chunkSize;
              }
                    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
                        //  Only read the heading row, and the rows that are configured in $this->_startRow and $this->_endRow
                        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }

             echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';
            /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);


            echo '<hr />';


            /**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
            $chunkSize = 20;
            /**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
            $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

            /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter that we've Instantiated  **/
            $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

            /**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
            for ($startRow = 1; $startRow <= 2000; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
                echo 'Loading WorkSheet using configurable filter for headings row 1 and for rows ',$startRow,' to ',($startRow+$chunkSize-1),'<br />';
                /**  Tell the Read Filter, the limits on which rows we want to read this iteration  **/
                $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
                $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_sqlite3;
                $cacheSettings = array( 
                    'cacheTime' => 600
                );
                PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);
                /**  Load only the rows that match our filter from $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
                //  Do some processing here
                $range_xl="A".($startRow).":X".($startRow + $chunkSize);
                echo "$range_xl.<br>";
                $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray($range_xl,null,true,true,true);
                //var_dump($sheetData);
                unset($objPHPExcel);
                //store data into array..
                $i=0;$h=1;
                foreach($sheetData as $rec)
                {
                    foreach($rec as $part)
                    {
                        $items[$i]=$part; //echo "items $i]=" ; echo $items[$i];echo "<br>";
                        $i=$i+1;            
                    }
                    $i=0;//1 row completed
                    $h=$h+1;//echo $items[0]."<br>";
    //echo "<br>---------------------<br>";             
    //start loading a row into database..
    if($h>4) {
    //store excel values
    $sno=trim($items[0]);echo $sno."<br>";
    $cat=trim($items[1]);
    $id_xl=trim($items[2]);
    $name=trim($items[3]);
    ....
```

Comment: I suspect it's a memory problem.  And even though you've set memory_limit, I know from experience that there's usually a hard limit in place on your server, which cannot be exceeded using the `ini_set()` like that.

Comment: What is your Excel file size ?

Comment: make the converter or plugin you are using is updated.

Comment: @cale_b : thats why i am trying to split the results as chunks and doing it. is there any better way to handle this ?

Comment: @IsaacRajaei : I am the latest version download from PHPExcel Git